# VS Code Jupyter Notebooks Markdown for links not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to setup a link in vs code Jupyter notebook. No matter which way I try to do it, it does not seem to work. my last attempt was with an [id] tag, still no joy!

```
for more explanation on headers see [here] [goog] 
[goog]: https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps
```

Not sure if there is a bug in VS Code or if it's me, more likely the latter, any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you are not mixing HTML markup with pure markdown. If you try to nest a link inside a

or table cell, it will not work. You must use simple markdown exclusively.

[See the basic markdown here](https://commonmark.org/help/)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to learn some basic markdown syntax:

```
[goog](https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps)
```

then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it will be:

[goog](https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps)

`[xxx] https://...` is another use to assign a label to a link to facilitate reference:

```
...
[goog][1]
...
...
...
[1]: https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps
[2]: ...
[3]: ...
THE END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

`__[https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps](for more explanation on headers see here)__`

this will return following:

https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps (for more explanation on headers see here)